# How to overwrite 2-D numpy multi times symmetrically with given index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to change values in matrix a with given index matrix d and matrix e.

And the matrix should always be symmetrical.

What I come up with is to overwrite the primal matrix with given index, and try to make it symmetrical, then go for another overwrite, until all the given index matrix have been gone through. It's not efficient.

But I'm stuck with how make it symmetrical.

For example:

```
a = np.ones([4,4],dtype=np.object)         #the primal matrix
d = np.array([[1],
              [2],
              [0],
              [0]])             #the first index matrix
a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],d] =2      #the element change to 2 with the indexes shown in d matrix
```

Now the result is:

```
a = np.array([[1 2 1 1]
              [1 1 2 1]
              [2 1 1 1]
              [2 1 1 1]])
```

After making it symmetrical (if a[ i ][ j ] was selected in  d matrix, a[ j ][ i ] should also be changed to 2,  how to do this part).

The expected output should be :

```
a = np.array([[1 2 2 2]
              [2 1 2 1]
              [2 2 1 1]
              [2 1 1 1]])
```

Then, for another overwrite again:

```
e = np.array([[0],[2],[1],[1]])
a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],e] =3
```

Now the result is:

```
a = np.array([[3 2 2 2]
              [2 1 3 1]
              [2 3 1 1]
              [2 3 1 1]])
```

Make it symmetrical, (I don't know how to do this part) the final output should be : (overwrite the values if they were given 2 or 1 before)

```
a = np.array([[3 2 2 2]
              [2 1 3 3]
              [2 3 1 1]
              [2 3 1 1]])
```

What should I do to get symmetrical matrix?

And, is there anyway to change the primal matrix a directly to get the final result? In a more efficient way?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply switch the first and second indices and apply the change, the result would be symmetrical:

```
a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], d] = 2 
a[d, np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]] = 2
```

output:

```
[[1 2 2 2]
 [2 1 2 1]
 [2 2 1 1]
 [2 1 1 1]]
```

Same with any number of other changes:

```
a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], e] = 3
a[e, np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]] = 3
```

output:

```
[[3 2 2 2]
 [2 1 3 3]
 [2 3 1 1]
 [2 3 1 1]]
```